# Cleaning corpus

Tags: machine-learning, classification, text-mining

I have a classifier that I want to use on short documents and I need to improve quality of the corpus used for training.  I have 250,000 documents and manual inspection is expensive.

The collection of short documents has been pre-labelled by a collection of rules as good or bad.  The accuracy of this pre-processing step has been assessed by sampling to be around 98% or higher.  When I train the classifier on 80% of the corpus and test its accuracy on the remaining 20%, it has a 98% accuracy.

What I am wondering is this:  if I filter the corpus and remove the documents for which there is disagreement and retrain and repeat, can I expect to arrive at a corpus for which the classifier agrees with the original labeling process within some small margin of error (less than 1%)?

```
EDIT:
```

After finding a corpus that appears to be clean, I would manually inspect the documents that were rejected.  I expect there would be around 5000 (2% of 250,000)

Comment: Why would you want to do this? If you suspect classifier is correctly labelling all of the points, despite noise in the label, then your classifier is already perfectly labelling all of the points. If you're uncertain about the labels you could hand-label a small subset of points, then do something like label spreading/label propagation/fitting your classifier on these points and find the disagreement between that model and the remaining data-points.

Comment: One word: boss. I need to find a way to reassure that the corpus is clean or the classifier can not be improved. One concern is that after running this cycle multiple times, I get more items kicked out each time.. so the first classifier kicks out say 100 and then after training on the remainder, the next classifier rejects 125 more and so on. The number of cycles to reach a target accuracy most likely depends on the starting accuracy and the label noise.

Comment: Is this accuracy on your training set or cross-validation accuracy?

Comment: I don't have a pristine corpus to cross-validate against so it would have to be the training set.

Comment: I'd be suspicious of a classifier that obtains perfect classification on a large corpus. I'd be suspicious of rejecting disagreed labels. Explain to your boss that the model is retrained on 100% of the data before being deployed and call it a day.